# Я хочу сделать проект на питоне, но что-то интересное, не календарь, бот, калькулятор

Tags: python, проект

Я новичек в программировании, но хочу начать свой проект. Идеи никаких нет, в интернете все очень банально, например калькулятор, календарь, бот в тг. Надеюсь, что вы подскажете что-то интересное

Comment: Устройтесь на работу. Там вам много интересного дадут :) Можете еще попробовать биржи фриланса пошерстить

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант сделать консольный текстовый квиз на ООП.

После запуска программы пользователь вводит имя, а затем ему по очереди задаются 10 вопросов с 4 вариантами ответа. Чтобы ответить на вопрос, пользователь вводит номер правильного ответа. В конце викторины программа выводит количество баллов, которое набрал пользователь.

Программа должна быть написана в парадигме ООП.
К примеру, вы можете организовать объектную модель следующим образом

- Класс Question c полями text, answers и correct_id
- Класс Quiz с полями questions, username и score

Из простого как вариант. Ну и во многом зависит от скиллов. Можно нечто подобное реализовать например на фреймворке Django.